# How to get round Price Value in Grand Total Magento 1.9.2?

Tags: magento-1.9, database

[image]

How can I achieve round price value in Grand Total?

Comment: Thats weird, i can see 4 magento version tags.. which version you are using?

Comment: it's mention above

Comment: Do you just need rounded price for grand total or for all the prices?

Comment: For price conversion you can use [this](https://marketplace.magento.com/etws-et-currencymanager.html) module this module Allows you to manage the price display in an easy way: to show a custom currency symbol, the number of decimals, the symbol's position, and so on.

Comment: @Lalit838 - I have applied tax class on some products. I need rounded price for grand total because product prices are not in decimal value.

Answer (score 0):

check this file from core

> Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address_Total_Grand

```
/**
     * Collect grand total address amount
     *
     * @param   Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address $address
     * @return  Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address_Total_Grand
     */
    public function collect(Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address $address)
    {
        $grandTotal     = $address->getGrandTotal();
        $baseGrandTotal = $address->getBaseGrandTotal();

        $store      = $address->getQuote()->getStore();
        $totals     = array_sum($address->getAllTotalAmounts());
        $totals     = $store->roundPrice($totals);
        $baseTotals = array_sum($address->getAllBaseTotalAmounts());
        $baseTotals = $store->roundPrice($baseTotals);

        $address->setGrandTotal(round($grandTotal+$totals)); // round here
        $address->setBaseGrandTotal(round($baseGrandTotal+$baseTotals)); // round here
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Add grand total information to address
     *
     * @param   Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address $address
     * @return  Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address_Total_Grand
     */
    public function fetch(Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address $address)
    {
        $address->addTotal(array(
            'code'  => $this->getCode(),
            'title' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Grand Total'),
            'value' => $address->getGrandTotal(),
            'area'  => 'footer',
        ));
        return $this;
    }
```